# what does it mean "dynamic disks support MBR and GPT"?

Tags: partitioning, mbr, gpt, dynamic-disk, basic-disk

I'm confused "Do Dynamic disks have GPT and MBR or not?" while in [this page, number 3 in table it says there is no partition in Dynamic disks against basic disks that have GPT and MBR partition styles](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-basic-disk-and-dynamic-disk/) on the other hand in [this page of microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/basic-and-dynamic-disks#dynamic-disks) it says "Like basic disks, dynamic disks can use the MBR or GPT partition styles on systems that support both." which one? and what does it mean second quote exactly?

Comment: Microsoft documents are correct.  The other page is just incorrect on so many levels.  It’s not even worth submitting an answer since it would draw attention to that horribly incorrect inaccurate website selling trash exam preparation material.  However, the trashy website, technically doesn’t indicate that dynamic partitions don’t use MBR/GPT.  The single sentence just describes the differences between basic and dynamic partitions.

Comment: If thinking of ever installing Linux, to not convert a drive to dynamic. Its another proprietary configuration from Microsoft that does fully work with Linux. And Microsoft makes it easy to convert to dynamic, but has no undo. Its suggestion on undo is total backup, erase drive & restore data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPT and MBR are disk partitioning formats. They allow a single physical disk to be split into smaller partitions (volumes)

Basic disk is a plain simple GPT or MBR disk. Each partition on a basic disk spans a linear continuous region on the disk. Dynamic disk OTOH is an abstraction layer above that so it can be constructed on either GPT or MBR formats. It allows the creation of logical partitions that can be easily extended (expand in size), spanned multiple empty regions on a single or multiple physical disks or a software RAID volume for speed or data integrity...

Comment: the comments that was here, was my answer; why is gone?